# localStorage in static NextJS site: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use localStorage on a NextJS static site but running into the localStorage is not defined error.

My code for the component where the error shows, is:

```
export default function Category() {

const [cart, setCart] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("myCart") || ""
    );

 useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("myCart", cart);
    }, [cart]);

function addItem() {
            setCart("item")   
    }

return (
<>
<button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>)
</>
);
}
```

Any idea if it's possible to use localStorage on a NextJS static site or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [use-persisted-state](https://github.com/donavon/use-persisted-state):

```js
import createPersistedState from 'use-persisted-state';

const useCartState = createPersistedState('cart');

export default function Category() {
     
  const [cart, setCart] = useCartState('');

  function addItem() {
    setCart("item");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>)
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is available through the `window` object. Since Next.js runs through the code twice, once in the server during SSR and once in the client, it won't be able to access the `window` object during SSR, hence the error.

You'd want to check if the `window` object is present and then access the `localStorage` like this —

```
!!window ? window.localStorage.getItem("myCart") : ""
```

Check if `window` object is present in the environment, if present get the value from `localStorage`, else return empty string.

Comment: window object is not present in NextJS initially when page loads, due to SSR when in development, thus the error. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911#discussioncomment-148457

Answer (score 0):

this is how to do it using a technique called lazy initialization. create the function on top of the component.

```js
const getInitialState =()=>localStorage.getItem("myCart");
export default function Category() {

const [cart, setCart] = useState(
        getInitialState || ""
    );

 useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("myCart", cart);
    }, [cart]);

function addItem() {
            setCart("item")   
    }

return (
<>
<button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>)
</>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getInitialState =()=>typeof window !== 'undefined' 
    ? localStorage.getItem('myCart') 
    : undefined;
export default function Category() {

const [cart, setCart] = useState(
        getInitialState || ""
    );

      useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      localStorage.setItem("myCart", cart);
    }
  }, [cart]);


function addItem() {
            setCart("item")   
    }

return (
<>
<button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>)
</>
);
}
```